# How to scrape real-time data from a website that requires login?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping

**Hey, I'm trying to scrape the price of an item from an online marketplace called Buff.163,
they have an API but still require you to login before returning any data.**

**Error received:**

```
"{ code: "Login Required" error: "\u8bf7\u5148\u767b\u5f55" extra: null }"
```

**Formula used:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(CHAR(10),SPLIT(IMPORTDATA(CONCAT("https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods/sell_order?game=csgo&goods_id=",REGEXEXTRACT(B3,"goods_id=(\d+)")&"&max_paintwear="&REGEXEXTRACT(B7,"max_paintwear=(....)")))&CHAR(10),CHAR(10))))
```

*I used "&" after the first 2 CONCAT arguments to add the "max_paintwear" value since 2 is the max amount of arguments CONCAT allows, not sure if that's causing any issues.*

**Example URL used to get the "goods_id" and "paintwear" value:**
https://buff.163.com/market/goods?goods_id=43106#max_paintwear=0.03

**Final URL it should be scraping the data from:**
https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods/sell_order?game=csgo&goods_id=43106&max_paintwear=0.03

**Here's a link to the google sheet I was using to test solutions:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZVt8_0hjiFwl23snjdrzNm0XCWQ9PRct4ECIG-Ke3Rc/

**Any help is greatly appreciated ❤️**